# Is an S3 Object the same as a file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was looking at the growth of my bucket (I run an image hosting social network), and the new number of objects per month is ten times larger than what I expect from seeing the number of files people upload thru my website.

Of course, I have a variable number of thumbnails and also other sources of files, but a 10x deviation from the expectation is quite massive.

If my bucket metrics indicate 500,000 new objects in a month, does that actually mean 500,000 new files?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, an object is a file.

Comment: Thanks, then I have to figure out what all these files are!